# django get_queryset() is redundant, since we have get_context_data()?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-views

I have been always wondering if get_queryset() is redundant in django. As we know, get_queryset() returns a list of objects back to the page, but to return this list of objects, we can also always specify it in get_context_data(), and get_context_data() can return many more variables, not just a list. An example can be seen as follows:

> Return a list of children book by get_queryset()

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Book

class ChildrenBook(ListView):
    model = Book
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qset = super(BookListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return qset.filter(type="children")
```

> Return a list of children book by get_context_data()

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Book

class ChildrenBook(ListView):
    model = Book
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['children_book_list'] = Book.objects.filter(type="children")
        return context
```

To the best of my knowledge, I do not find anything that get_queryset() can do but get_context_data cannot. Anyone can find some situation where only get_queryset() can be used and illustrate its necessity?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the actual django source code you’ll see why overloading only `get_context_data` is a bad idea unless you want to have to rewrite a whole bunch of code:

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """
    A base view for displaying a list of objects.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

        if not allow_empty:
            # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
            # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
            # queryset in memory.
            if (self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None
                    and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists')):
                is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
            else:
                is_empty = len(self.object_list) == 0
            if is_empty:
                raise Http404(_("Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
                        % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Essentially, not overloading the `get_queryset` method won’t handle cases like when there are no records in the filter because the `object_list` property won’t be set correctly.

Comment: I'm not talking about the necessity of overloading get_queryset() and get_context_data(). What I mean in the original question is, both get_queryset() and get_context_data() send data to the front-end, and I think one method to send all the data to the front-end would be enough, without a second method.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the request/response cycle, **neither** `get_queryset()` nor `get_context_data()` send data to the front end.  The function that sends data to the user, as you can see from the pasted code, is `get()` because it calls `render_to_response`.  Both of these methods are called along the way, at different points.  And each one does different things.  Your question in the OP was:  `if get_queryset() is redundant in django`.  As you can see in the base django code above, it isn’t.